# Is it possible to get the last "N" IDs from a ContentProvider bulkInsert?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contentprovider, database-performance

### The problem

Say that I want to insert 1000 elements on a table using a `ContentProvider`. I'd normally use `bulkInsert` for that.

But what if I want the IDs of the successful insert operations? I can't get that information through the `bulkInsert` method, since it only returns a `long`.

So I wonder, is there a way to do a bulk insert and get the newly inserted IDs?

### What I'm doing now

The solution that came up on my mind was to either get the last "N" inserted rows and get the IDs after the `bulkInsert`, or to make a query based on a column of the inserted rows (Let's say, column 'name').

Either way works, but do I really need to take this extra step? It feels a little redundant...

**Example of my `bulkInsert`:**

```
final SQLiteDatabase db = mOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    switch (sUriMatcher.match(uri)) {
        case BLAH: {
            db.beginTransaction();
            int rCount = 0;
            for (ContentValues value : values) {
                long _id = db.insert(SaiteContract.BlahEntry.TABLE_NAME, null, value);
                if (_id != -1) {
                    rCount++;
                }
            }
            db.setTransactionSuccessful();
            db.endTransaction();

            Context context = getContext();
            if (context != null) {
                context.getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri,null);
            }

            return rCount;
        }
        // Other tables
        default:
            return super.bulkInsert(uri,values);
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you need that list for?

Comment: I'm inserting into a many to many relationship tables, I need those to associate with the other table.

Comment: Gotcha. It looks like you are returning the count of the records that you inserted, though, not the actual id values

Comment: Yes I am, because I'm using a content provider. So I'm overriding that method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The contract of `bulkInsert` is to return the number of affected rows, so I wouldn't recommend changing that.  If you need to make an arbitrary call, you can use `ContentResolver.call()`, which returns a Bundle.  For example, in your provider implementation:

```
@Override
public Bundle call(String method, String args, Bundle extras) {
    if (method.equals("customInsert")) {
        ContentValues[] values = extras.getParcelableArray("contentValues")
        // do bulk insert and return list of ids in a new Bundle
    }
}
```

Then simply call

```
Bundle result = getContentResolver().call(...);
List<Long> ids = result.getLongArray("ids");
```

Comment: Oh, nice! I'll try that one :)